# getting Null value for jsonObject in android app

Tags: php, android, json

I have problem with getting value from json object .json_encode return null string to android.

Logcat :

```
05-01 22:36:21.653: D/Create Response(801): {}

05-01 22:36:21.653: W/System.err(801): org.json.JSONException: No value
for success

05-01 22:36:21.663: W/System.err(801):  at

org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)

05-01 22:36:21.663: W/System.err(801):  at 

org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:443)
```

MyPhp.php

```
<?php


header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');
$response = array();
// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['B_Name']) && isset($_POST['Au_Name']) && 
isset($_POST['Pub']) && isset($_POST['Pr']) && 
isset($_POST['B_Genre']))  {

$B_Name = $_POST['B_Name'];
$Au_Name = $_POST['Au_Name'];
$Pub = $_POST['Pub'];
$Pr = $_POST['Pr'];
$B_Genre = $_POST['B_Genre'];

// include db connect class
require_once( __DIR__ . '/android/db_connect.php');

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(Book_Name, Author_Name, Book_Genre, Price, Publication) VALUES('$B_Name', '$Au_Name', '$B_Genre', '$Pr', '$Pub')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";


 $encoded_rows = array_map('utf8_encode', $response);
   echo json_encode($encoded_rows);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

  $encoded_rows = array_map('utf8_encode', $response);
   echo json_encode($encoded_rows);
     }
} else {

  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
  $encoded_rows = array_map('utf8_encode', $response);
  echo json_encode($encoded_rows);
  }
```

And here is my piece of doInBackground :

```
        String B_Name = BookName.getText().toString();
        String Au_Name = AuthorName.getText().toString();
        String Pub = Publication.getText().toString();
        String Pr = Price.getText().toString();
        String B_Genre = BookGenre.getText().toString();


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("B_Name", B_Name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Au_Name", Au_Name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pub", Pub));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pr", Pr));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("B_Genre", B_Genre));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),    
       MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();


            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Looks like your json string is empty: "{}"

Comment: Buddy - I know that but why ??

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue is with PHP code. [check echo method of php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp).

I have not worked on php but I think `echo json_encode($encoded_rows);` statement simply prints json in string format. Check where you are returning json string in response.